# gnome desktop is not working

Tags: linux, gnome, redhat-enterprise-linux, gnome3

Gnome desktop is not working for my redhat PC. The version of gnome desktop3 is 3.14.2-2.el7. When I exec **ps -A | grep gnome**, it returns

```
2384 ?        00:00:00 gnome-session
2420 ?        00:00:00 gnome-settings-
2452 ?        00:00:00 gnome-shell
```

When I exec **systemctl status gdm -l**, it shows gdm is working OK. One problem listed in **/var/log/messages** is:

> gnome-session: gnome-session[2384]: dconf-WARNING: unable to open named profile (gdm): using the null configuration.

So, how to bring my gnome desktop back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with one line: **sudo yum update**. It provided me with a new gnome desktop. So the culprit is mismatch version between gnome component.

Hopes this will help anyone else.